# Attribute error in NVDIA DIGITS installation

Tags: nvidia-digits

I tried to install NVIDIA DIGITS on ubuntu 14.04

I followed this website to install all the pre-requisites: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/BuildDigits.md
I couldn't set up the server

The command: ./digits-devserver returned this:

[The first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLfU3.png)

[The second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtDJT.png)

Please let me know how I can tackle this attribute error(AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nanprod')

Comment: I just found out that some dependencies' requirements are different for digits and caffe. DIGITS needs matplotlib version1.5.2 while scikit-image 0.14.0 has requirement matplotlib>=2.0.0. digits 6.1.1 has requirement Pillow<=3.1.2,>=2.3.0 while scikit-image 0.14.0 has requirement pillow>=4.3.0.

Comment: Also, I am not able to uninstall python-dateutil 1.5. pandas 0.23.0 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0